# 301 redirect with subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have put the following content in my .htaccess file. What I want is redirect all mydomain.com/ to www.mydomain.com/. At the same time I want subdomain.mydomain.com/ should not get redirected anywhere. With the below code, I am able to achieve my 1st goal. But it redirects http://subdomain.mydomain.com/ to http://www.mydomain.com/subdomain. Please guide me on how to achieve both my modifying .htaccess.
    `RewriteEngine On`
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]`
    `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it more restrictive, i.e. apply rule only when host name is `mydomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```